# Issues in using Cofoundry and individual user acount Authentication and Authorisation in same Web application

Tags: authorization, cofoundry

If I add

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddCofoundry(Configuration);
```

to my Startup.cs my Authentication and Authorisation is failing.

If I disable the above lines in Startup.cs `@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))`  is true, however if I uncomment it `@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))` is  always false despite the user being logged in.

Is it not possible to use Authorisation, Authentication and Cofoundry in the same application?

Answer (score 0):

Cofoundry has it's own user management system and adds authentication automatically to the pipeline to support this. See the [User Area docs](https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/content-management/user-areas) on how to create your own custom user areas.

There's not much support for running your own authentication mechanisms alongside Cofoundry at this time(improvements are planned), but you can override the existing auth registration and customize it to your needs by implementing your own `IAuthConfiguration` implementation, including the code in [`DefaultAuthConfiguration`](https://github.com/cofoundry-cms/cofoundry/blob/1a45165dc499c66690b4b3660a26b664c8e8e0f9/src/Cofoundry.Web/App_Start/StartupTasks/ServiceConfigurationTasks/DefaultAuthConfiguration.cs) to ensure Cofoundry is configured correctly. For example:

```cs
using Cofoundry.Core.DependencyInjection;
using Cofoundry.Domain;
using Cofoundry.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Use an IDependencyRegistration instance to override the default implementation
/// </summary>
public class AuthDependencyRegistration : IDependencyRegistration
{
    public void Register(IContainerRegister container)
    {
        container.Register<IAuthConfiguration, CustomAuthConfiguration>(RegistrationOptions.Override());
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is a copy of the default config
/// </summary>
public class CustomAuthConfiguration : IAuthConfiguration
{
    private readonly IUserAreaDefinitionRepository _userAreaDefinitionRepository;
    private readonly IAuthCookieNamespaceProvider _authCookieNamespaceProvider;

    public CustomAuthConfiguration(
        IUserAreaDefinitionRepository userAreaDefinitionRepository,
        IAuthCookieNamespaceProvider authCookieNamespaceProvider
        )
    {
        _userAreaDefinitionRepository = userAreaDefinitionRepository;
        _authCookieNamespaceProvider = authCookieNamespaceProvider;
    }

    public void Configure(IMvcBuilder mvcBuilder)
    {
        var services = mvcBuilder.Services;
        var allUserAreas = _userAreaDefinitionRepository.GetAll();

        // Set default schema as specified in config, falling back to CofoundryAdminUserArea
        // Since any additional areas are configured by the implementor there shouldn't be multiple
        // unless the developer has misconfigured their areas.
        var defaultSchemaCode = allUserAreas
            .OrderByDescending(u => u.IsDefaultAuthSchema)
            .ThenByDescending(u => u is CofoundryAdminUserArea)
            .ThenBy(u => u.Name)
            .Select(u => u.UserAreaCode)
            .First();

        var defaultScheme = CofoundryAuthenticationConstants.FormatAuthenticationScheme(defaultSchemaCode);

        var authBuilder = mvcBuilder.Services.AddAuthentication(defaultScheme);
        var cookieNamespace = _authCookieNamespaceProvider.GetNamespace();

        foreach (var userAreaDefinition in allUserAreas)
        {
            var scheme = CofoundryAuthenticationConstants.FormatAuthenticationScheme(userAreaDefinition.UserAreaCode);

            authBuilder
                .AddCookie(scheme, cookieOptions =>
                {
                    cookieOptions.Cookie.Name = cookieNamespace + userAreaDefinition.UserAreaCode;
                    cookieOptions.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    cookieOptions.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                    cookieOptions.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userAreaDefinition.LoginPath))
                    {
                        cookieOptions.LoginPath = userAreaDefinition.LoginPath;
                    }
                });
        }

        mvcBuilder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    }
}
```